# War Card Game Problems

Tags: c++

I am trying to code the "War" Card Game, and I am having problems getting the comparisons right. I have the rest of the programming right, and half the comparisons (comparing the suits) but I cannot figure out why my face value rankings are not working. The function that the problem is, is determineWinner, but I will post the whole program for any overall feedback. I know mapping would be an easier way to do this but I have not been "taught" it. Please stick to for/if/vector library if possible.

[Obviously Player 1 did not win every "trick". Whoever wins the first trick, is output as the winner for the rest of them.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPO0O.png)

Thank you!

````
/*
             Suits                           Value Rank:                                 Suit:
       0: Spades 0 - 12                Ace->King->Queen->Jack->10->9.....0         S > H > D > C
       1: Hearts 13 - 25               n % 13 = #0-12 (Face Value)                 n / 13 = 0,1,2,3 (Suit)
       2: Diamonds 26 - 38
       3: Clubs 39-51

       0 - K
       1 - A
       2 
       3
       4
       5
       6
       7
       8
       9
       10 - T
       11 - J
       12 - Q
*/


                // 1. FINISH CONVERTING PLAYERHANDS TO HAVE FACE VALUE AND SUIT x
                // 2. Code the tricks x
                // 3. Code comparisons for every trick
                // 3. Points for tricks and tracking points x
                // 4. Determining winner and determing who wins in a tie x

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime> //rand function
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Card { //struct holds faceValue and suit for use in displaying proper output
    int faceValue;
    char suit;
};

int generatePlayerCount();
int getCardsPerPlayer(int playerCount);
vector <int> generateDeck(vector <int> &deckOfCards);
vector <vector <Card>> generatePlayersHands(int playerCount, int cardsPerPerson, vector <int> &deckOfCards, vector <vector <Card>> &playersHands);
int playTricks(vector <vector <Card>>& playersHands, const int playerCount, int cardsPerHand, vector <int>& score);
int determineWinner(vector <vector <Card>>& playersHands, const int playerCount, int cardsPerHand, vector <int>& score, int trickCount);
void outputWinners(const int playerCount, vector <int>& score);

int const DECK_SIZE = 52;

int main()
{
    do
    {
        srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));
        int playerCount = generatePlayerCount(); //sets player count
        int cardsPerHand = getCardsPerPlayer(playerCount); //sets cards each player gets
        vector <vector <Card>> playersHands(playerCount); // creates a vector of vectors, each element of the vector stores a playersHand
        vector <int> deckOfCards(DECK_SIZE); //creates a vector of size DECK_SIZE
        vector <int> score(playerCount, 0); // vector to keep players scores

        generateDeck(deckOfCards); //initializes deck to 0-51
        playersHands = generatePlayersHands(playerCount, cardsPerHand, deckOfCards, playersHands); //sets playersHands = to generated playersHands vector of vectors
        playTricks(playersHands, playerCount, cardsPerHand, score);
        outputWinners(playerCount, score);
            
    } while (cin.get());
    return 0;
}


int generatePlayerCount() // generates 2-6 players inclusive
{
    int playerCount = (rand() % 5 + 2);
    return playerCount;
}


int getCardsPerPlayer(int playerCount) // calculates nuumber of cards each player gets based on how many players there are
{
    int cardsPerPerson = 52 / playerCount; 
    return cardsPerPerson;
}


vector <int> generateDeck(vector <int> &deckOfCards) // generates and initializes a deck of cards 0-51
{
    for (int i = 0; i < DECK_SIZE; i++)
    {
        deckOfCards[i] = i;
    }
    return deckOfCards;
}


vector <vector <Card>> generatePlayersHands(int playerCount, int cardsPerPerson, vector<int>& deckOfCards, vector <vector <Card>>& playersHands) // generates players hand w/ numbers only, hands need to be converted to have suit and rank
    {
    int randomElement;
    playersHands.resize(playerCount); // resizes vector to have enough space for generated # of players
    for (int player = 0; player < playerCount; player++) //deals all of the first players cards, then moves to the next
    {
        for (int numOfCards = 0; numOfCards < cardsPerPerson; numOfCards++) // deals to a player until they have reached "cardsPerPerson"
        {
            if (!deckOfCards.empty()) {
                randomElement = rand() % deckOfCards.size(); //generates random element out of deckOfCards and stores it to be erased from vector
                int cardInDeck = deckOfCards[randomElement];
                int suit = cardInDeck / 13; // Calculate suit 0-3
                int faceValue = cardInDeck % 13; // Calculate face value 0-12
                char suitChar;
               
                switch (suit) {
                    case 0: // n / 13 = 0 = Spades
                        {
                            suitChar = 'S';
                            break;
                        }
                    case 1: // n / 13 = 1 = Hearts
                    {
                        suitChar = 'H';
                        break;
                    }
                    case 2: // n / 13 = 2 = Diamonds
                    {
                        suitChar = 'D';
                        break;
                    }
                    case 3: // n / 13 = 0 = Clubs
                    {
                        suitChar = 'C';
                        break;
                    }
                }
                Card displayedCard = {faceValue, suitChar};
                playersHands[player].push_back(displayedCard); //adds card face value w/ suit to current players hand
                deckOfCards.erase(remove(deckOfCards.begin(), deckOfCards.end(), cardInDeck), deckOfCards.end()); // deletes the card in deck by deleting it by value rather than index, index causes duplicates
            }
        }
    }
    for (int player = 0; player < playerCount; player++) // Loops through each player until they have output all their cards
    {
        cout << "Player " << player + 1 << "'s Hand: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < playersHands[player].size(); i++) //Outputs each card until size of vector is hit
        {
            if (playersHands[player][i].faceValue == 0)
            {
                cout << "K"; // faceValue = 0 is a King
            }
            else if (playersHands[player][i].faceValue == 1)
            {
                cout << "A"; // faceValue = 1 is an Ace
            }
            else if (playersHands[player][i].faceValue == 10)
            {
                cout << "T"; //faceValue = 10 is T
            }
            else if (playersHands[player][i].faceValue == 11)
            {
                cout << "J"; //faceValue = 11 is a Jack
            }
            else if (playersHands[player][i].faceValue == 12)
            {
                cout << "Q"; //faceValue = 12 is a Queen
            }
            else 
            {
                cout << playersHands[player][i].faceValue; //display default faceValue
            }
            cout << playersHands[player][i].suit << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "Let's Play!" << endl << endl;
    return playersHands;   
}

int playTricks(vector<vector<Card>>& playersHands, const int playerCount, int cardsPerHand, vector <int>& score)
{
    int trickCount = 1;
    while (trickCount <= cardsPerHand) // tricks continue until all cards have been played
    {
        cout << "Trick " << trickCount << ":" << endl;
        
        for (int player = 0; player < playerCount; player++) // outputs score for each player per trick
        {
            cout << "Player " << player + 1 << ": " << score[player] << "   ";     
        }
        cout << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < playerCount; i++) // changes to cards to proper output
        {
            char faceChar;

            if (playersHands[i][trickCount - 1].faceValue == 0) {
                faceChar = 'K';
                cout << setw(6) << setfill(' ') << faceChar << playersHands[i][trickCount - 1].suit << "       ";

            }
            else if (playersHands[i][trickCount - 1].faceValue == 1) {
                faceChar = 'A';
                cout << setw(6) << setfill(' ') << faceChar << playersHands[i][trickCount - 1].suit << "       ";

            }
            else if (playersHands[i][trickCount - 1].faceValue == 10) {
                faceChar = 'T';
                cout << setw(6) << setfill(' ') << faceChar << playersHands[i][trickCount - 1].suit << "       ";

            }
            else if (playersHands[i][trickCount - 1].faceValue == 11) {
                faceChar = 'J';
                cout << setw(6) << setfill(' ') << faceChar << playersHands[i][trickCount - 1].suit << "       ";

            }
            else if (playersHands[i][trickCount - 1].faceValue == 12) {
                faceChar = 'Q';
                cout << setw(6) << setfill(' ') << faceChar << playersHands[i][trickCount - 1].suit << "       ";

            }
            else {
                cout << setw(6) << playersHands[i][trickCount - 1].faceValue << playersHands[i][trickCount - 1].suit << "       ";
            }
        }        
        int winner = determineWinner(playersHands, playerCount, cardsPerHand, score, trickCount); // determines player that won
        score[winner]++; // increments score of player who won
        cout << endl << "Player " << winner + 1 << " wins!" << endl << endl;
        trickCount = trickCount + 1; // starts next trick
    }
    return 0;
}

int determineWinner(vector<vector<Card>>& playersHands, const int playerCount, int cardsPerHand, vector <int>& score, int trickCount)
{
    int currentWinner = 0;
    vector<Card> currentTrickCards(playerCount); //

    for (int player = 0; player < playerCount; player++)
    {
        if (!playersHands[player].empty() && trickCount <= playersHands[player].size())
        {
            currentTrickCards[player] = playersHands[player][trickCount - 1]; //moves the cards from the current trick, into their own vector (for easier comparison) vs. comparing certain elements of x amount of vectors
        }
    }

    Card winningCard = currentTrickCards[0]; //sets winningCard to the first card in the vector
    

    for (int player = 1; player < playerCount; player++)
    {
         Card& currentCard = currentTrickCards[player]; //sets current card to be compared to the winning card
         string faceRankings = "23456789TJQKA"; //Ace high
        if (faceRankings.find(currentCard.faceValue) < faceRankings.find(winningCard.faceValue)) //takes current/winningCards face value, and finds it in string faceRanking, compares the index of both
        {
            winningCard = currentCard;
            currentWinner = player;
        }
        
        if (currentCard.faceValue == winningCard.faceValue)
        {
            string suitRankings = "SHDC"; // S > H > D > C
            if (suitRankings.find(currentCard.suit) > suitRankings.find(winningCard.suit))
            {
                winningCard = currentCard;
                currentWinner = player;
            }
            
        }
    }

    return currentWinner;
}

void outputWinners(const int playerCount, vector<int>& score)
{
    bool foundTie;
    int topScore = -1;
    vector <int> winnersVec;

    for (int player = 0; player < playerCount; player++) //finds highest score, stores it in vector, if higher score is found, deletes old score & replaces
    {
        if (score[player] > topScore)
        {
            topScore = score[player];
            winnersVec.clear(); // gets rid of old winner
            winnersVec.push_back(player); // stores new winner
        }
        else if (score[player] == topScore)
        {
            winnersVec.push_back(player);
        }
    }

    cout << setw(25) << setfill('+') << "\n"; // outputs line of +'s
    cout << "Final Scores:" << endl;  
    
    for (int players = 0; players < playerCount; players++)
    {
        cout << "Player " << players + 1 << ": " << score[players];    
        if (score[players] == topScore) //if score is highest score, mark it w an *
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << setw(25) << setfill('+') << "\n";
}```
````

Comment: It looks like you are comparing integers here `if (faceRankings.find(currentCard.faceValue)` when your faceRanking string is looking for a character value. I don't see in your code where you are converting the ints to a string for use in the index string comparison.

Comment: @JustinEdwards, the find function finds the value of currentCard (5 for example) in the string faceRanking, and returns the element does it not? I could be mistaken

Comment: @BladeCJ `string::find` returns an index into the string, so it seems that both your comparisons are incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

`faceRankings.find(currentCard.faceValue)` is searching for an integer between 0 and 12 in your string. The integer gets converted to its ASCII value which doesn't match any of the characters in the string, so both calls will return `faceRankings.end()`, so your condition will never be true, so player 1 always wins unless the faces of the cards match.

You'll need to change `faceRankings` into a vector of `int`s, e.g:

```
std::vector<int> faceRankings = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 0, 1 };
```

Kudos to your teachers for devising the weirdest way I've ever seen of representing cards, I've no idea why you'd make a king `0`. Given how bizarre the rankings are, to avoid mistakes I'd use an enum rather than magic numbers for the rankings:

```
enum class Face
{
  Ace = 1,
  _2,
  _3,
  _4,
  _5,
  _6,
  _7,
  _8,
  _9,
  _10,
  Jack,
  Queen,
  King = 0
};
```

Then the vector is more understandable:

```
std::vector<Face> faceRankings = { 
  Face::_2, 
  Face::_3, 
  Face::_4, 
  Face::_5, 
  Face::_6,
  Face::_7, 
  Face::_8, 
  Face::_9, 
  Face::_10, 
  Face::_Jack, 
  Face::_Queen, 
  Face::_King, 
  Face::_Ace
};
```